# Homebrew upgrade drops PHP: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libpsl/lib/libpsl.5.dylib

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, macos-mojave

Today I upgraded Homebrew and this causes PHP versions (7.2 - 7.3) to be dropped. the following error is shown whenever I try to reinstall them:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libpsl/lib/libpsl.5.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/curl-openssl/bin/curl
Reason: image not found
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
DownloadError: Failed to download resource "php"
Download failed: https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.3.9.tar.xz
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Okay, I've solved this by installing this library `brew install libpsl`

then reinstall php `brew reinstall php@7.2 --build-from-source`

also the same for php@7.3

*Be aware that reinstalling php will reset all php configurations*

Comment: This was a life saver. Thanks

Comment: i ran both of the commands and restarted terminal but it had no effect on the error.

Comment: I had similar when running php 8.2. e.g. `dyld[1180]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
  Referenced from: <4DFABB9B-E15B-37C3-A4E9-496D6D2ED71E> /usr/local/Cellar/gd/2.3.3_4/lib/libgd.3.dylib` I was able to solve by running  `brew reinstall gd`.

Comment: Amazing! I have no idea what `libpsl` is, but this did the trick. 

Just FYI, I do get a warning that says:

`Warning: building from source is not supported!
You're on your own. Failures are expected so don't create any issues, please!`

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug after `php` was migrated to OpenSSH 1.1. There's no need to install `libpsl`.

The problem has been fixed by [pr-44048](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/44048). You should uninstall `libpsl` and reinstall `php`.

```sh
brew uninstall libpsl
brew reinstall php
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the Cellar folder and installing the PHP again worked for me.

```
rm -rf /Users/rafaelgomes/.composer/*
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/*
brew doctor ; brew update ; brew upgrade
brew install php
```

Answer (score 2):

I found various anwers to this, but basically I broke the permissions of my Cellar Directory and everything in it by running a stupid command trying to fix an error after installing NMAP.

So to fix it, I reinstalled brew and everything php related. That will correct any permissions and/or sym links. Sometimes you just gotta nuke everything and start over.

This is my specific error:

```
dyld[32102]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
  Referenced from: <SOME-0E3C-3E56-AEC8-LONG-ID> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gd/2.3.3_4/lib/libgd.3.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file),
'/opt/homebrew/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file),
'/usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 
'/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libtiff/4.5.1/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libtiff/4.5.1/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libtiff/4.5.1/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

This error occured any time i used php. Even `php -v`!

But before doing any of this, try `brew update` and `brew upgrade` you might just get lucky and nip it in the bud before you get into process of removing ALL php versions and reinstalling. But these are the steps i took to fix this error.

1. `rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup`
2. Then follow instructions here: [docs.brew.sh/Installation](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) to install brew. (as they change from time to time)
3. `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`
4. remove all versions of php
5. `brew search php` See if you have any remaining `php@7.4 ✔` check marks next to the php versions, remove those with `brew uninstall php@7.4`
6. i.e. `brew uninstall brew-php-switcher` (if you use it)
7. `brew upgrade`
8. `brew cleanup`
9. Then Re-install your php verisons. e.g. `brew install php@7.4`
10. Then Re-install brew-php-switcher (if you use it, i love it) `brew install brew-php-switcher`
11. Then once you're done, `brew-php-swticher 8.2` I love this tool! (Or replace 8.2 with what version you need, just use 7.4 or 8.0 etc)

Comment: I hit exactly the same libtiff error today, but in my case it was after installing deno. Your solution worked, thanks!

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know if this answer would immedaitely get voted out or stick around! Glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem. This is how I fix the issue after following a combination of instructions from [here](https://community.mrtrix.org/t/dyld-library-not-loaded-error-on-osx-10-13-4/1636/2) and also SO from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77219126/dyld45923-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-libavif-lib-libavif-15-dylib)

1. I rename the file.

   locate libtiff

in my case I could see that the file is locate here
`Cellar/libtiff/4.6.0/lib/libtiff.6.dylib`

```
mv Cellar/libtiff/4.6.0/lib/libtiff.6.dylib Cellar/libtiff/4.6.0/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
```

2. Then I installed both gd then I had this error

   php -v

   ```
   dyld[23974]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gd/lib/libgd.3.dylib
   Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.12_1/bin/php
   Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/gd/lib/libgd.3.dylib' (no such file), 
   '/usr/local/lib/libgd.3.dylib' (no such file), 
   '/usr/lib/libgd.3.dylib' (no such file)
   zsh: abort      php -v
   ```
3. brew reinstall gd after change the libtiff.5.dylib back libtiff.6.dylib as in STEP 1. *This is just to make sure nothing breaks in the future.*

   ```
    brew reinstall gb
   ```

   here[image]

Now when I do `php -v` the issue is fixed. [image]

I actually got here after trying to use `wp plugin list` after `brew upgrade`.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved this by doing the following

```
brew uninstall libpsl
brew remove php
brew install libpsl
brew install php@8.0
```