# dyld[45923]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib

Tags: macos, xampp, composer-php, homebrew

> ```
> dyld[45923]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib
>  Referenced from: <735019D8-AF6E-3CD1-9AD4-3BE47CB22D4F> /usr/local/Cellar/gd/2.3.3_5/lib/libgd.3.dylib
>  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/libavif/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/usr/local/Cellar/libavif/1.0.1/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/Cellar/libavif/1.0.1/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/libavif/1.0.1/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libavif.15.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
> ```

I updated MacOS to Sonoma and I had problem with XAMPP. So, I reinstalled XAMPP. Now this error is showing. I can't use PHP and Composer.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I had the same issue after installing macOS Ventura.

Try to reinstall gd:

```
brew reinstall gd
```

Comment: PHP somehow broke in my Mac running Ventura and kept getting an error similar to OP's, even when doing something as simple as checking the active PHP version. I have tried a variety of proposed solutions, including `brew update` and `brew upgrade`, which did not work. `brew reinstall gd` is the only solution that worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I have solve this issue follow bellow steps

```
brew update
brew cleanup
brew upgrade
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. May have been a sledgehammer to crack a nut, and the reinstall of gd accepted answer may have worked, but I had already started hitting the nut with the sledgehammer.  Anyway the nut cracked and php is working again.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue and discovered (with `brew update`) that there were a lot of outdated packages on my macOS workstation. Here is what fixed it:

```
brew upgrade
```